# Postgres server shutdown from simple select all on a small dataset from ActiveRecord query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, postgresql-9.3

I have the following endpoint in my rails app:

```
def index
 if params.key?(:start) 
      if params[:start].to_i.to_s == params[:start] #unix epoche time format
             p = Param
                    .where(devise_id: params[:devise_id])
                    .where('"TimeStamp" >= ?', Time.at(params[:start].to_i))
                    .order('created_at DESC')
      else
          raise Exceptions::RequestError, '...'
      end
end
```

So far so good. The `params` table has around 20000 entries for the desired `devise_id`. But one api call to return all 20000 entries  postgres  got shutdown with the following error message:

```
2016-12-08 12:22:58 CET LOG:  server process (PID 16510) was terminated by signal 9: Killed
2016-12-08 12:22:58 CET DETAIL:  Failed process was running: SELECT   COUNT(*) FROM "params" WHERE "params"."devise_id" = $1
2016-12-08 12:22:58 CET LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
```

I could not reproduce this postgresql  crash.

However unicorn is setup to timeout after 30 seconds. Testing this endpoint , sometimes the response takes slightly longer, so the `unicorn worker` is killed and another one is started by the unicorn master. 
(I did not think about this in the design, implementation phase and i am going to change that soon to some partitioning)
The database access takes some milliseconds but formatting all data in a ruby hash takes most of the time.

I would like now to understand why the postgresql server crashed and how prevent this. 20000 entries is almost nothing for psql.
This only appeared once but i would like to keep it that way ;)

Stack:

- psql (PostgreSQL) 9.3.13
- unicorn 5.1.0
- Rails 4.2.7
- Ruby 2.3.0

Answer (score 0):

This is probably overkill for you but since we had several cases of killed processes and postgresql server going into recovery mode and canceling all other sessions etc. we installed pgbouncer for connection pooling. This way database is shielded from a lot of these cases.